# why UPDATE answertable SET Ans-Farsi-value = `خیلی ناراضی` WHERE Ans-value =`Very Dissatisfied' generates 1064 error;

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE answertable SET Ans-Farsi-value = `خیلی ناراضی` WHERE Ans-value =`Very Dissatisfied`;
```

> **generates error**

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-Farsi-value = `خیلی ناراضی` WHERE Ans-value =`Very Dissatisfied`' at line 1

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query.

[image]

Comment: Including mathematical operators within table/column identifiers is a cataclysmically poor idea. Don't. Do. It.

Comment: Ok Strawberry, will consider it.